# Authorization failed in SVN

Tags: svn

Good Morning,

i have here a strange situation. I'm not able to commit new stuff to my repository.
That alone would not be strange enough to ask here. This behavior only occurs on one of my two laptops.

I have an older laptop with an identical operating system (Windows 10) with which I'm logged into the same network via VPN.

The version of TortoiseSVN is identical.
The credentials that I use for the commit are of course identical, too.

The message seems to indicate that the data is being rejected by the server. On the other hand, they work on a different computer.

I am a little desperate. Does anyone have any idea what to try?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the SVN Properties.
One of the URLS to the repository was

https://url_to_repo/   (that works for updates & commits)

the other one

svn:////url_to_repo/   (that only for updates)